# interactive online data plotting using python

Tags: python, html

Question: is it possible to recreate such functionality with python? http://itools.subhashbose.com/grapher/index.php

Backstory: We want to create a hybrid online teaching/computational resource for undergraduate students of our institute, running on a local server. I have worked only in matlab, and have fair bit experience in c++. so wanted to choose appropriate language (preferably open source, but not strictly) which can facilitate above functionality with mathematica cdf like properties. I wanted to learn python form long time so wanted to know if it can do the job. Dont want to use javascript (which i suppose is used in this page).

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/ comes to mind

Comment: i am also reading about the same but can it take data over html and plot it back in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fetching data from html have a look at this site: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html.

If you want to built your own site, there are small web frameworks like [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/). If you are interested in a more comprehensive web framework, check out Django: http://www.djangoproject.com/.

Matplotlib could be used to generate the plot e.g. in jpg or svg. The latter might give you the option to have the image respond to e.g. hovering over specific parts of the plot like in your example page.

Maybe also have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-chart-tools. From their webpage:

> django-chart-tools is a simple app for creating charts in django templates using Google Chart API.

Comment: Sorry for accepting answer so late but I was learning in it in the mean to see if thats what i needed! indeed it was! Thanks